# Do you have to be 18 yrs old to publish an app on the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there an age limit to who can publish apps on the App Store?

Comment: [Is there an age restriction to make/upload iOS apps?](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-age-restriction-to-make-upload-iOS-apps)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's most important thing, because u can find your parents provide the info to register the Apple Developer Account. And u also can find some young developers are invited to join the WWDC every year. So if u wanna publish your app, just do it!

Comment: I agree this comment. A good idea is the most important. [Melbourne schoolboy Yuma Soerianto impresses Apple CEO Tim Cook with his apps](https://www.news.com.au/technology/online/melbourne-schoolboy-yuma-soerianto-impresses-apple-ceo-tim-cook-with-his-apps/news-story/acdb6454e036cfd8c5545a5a6d545f6a)